# Is there any way to retain TextInput opacity in React Native even if editable is set to false?

Tags: react-native

I have a TextInput that when I set `editable={false}` the text opacity decreases. Is there anyway to make the opacity retain even if `editable` is set to `true`?

Please refer to the image below.

[image]

I'm expecting something like:

[image]

Just that the style is like `editable={true}` but cannot be edit by the user.

Answer (score 0):

you can make your own custom component and give the styles you want:-

```
  render() {
        const { containerStyle, keyboardType, returnKeyType, customStyles, multiline, isMandatory,
          hint, title, image, titleStyle, autoCapitalize, secureTextEntry, editable, isPassword,
          onFocus, renderExtraItem, ...props } = this.props;
    
        return (
          <View style={[styles.viewTextInput, containerStyle]}>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
              {title && <Text style={[styles.textLabel, titleStyle]}>
                {title}
                {isMandatory && <Text style={{ color: ColorConstants.RED }}> *</Text>}
              </Text>}
              {renderExtraItem && renderExtraItem()}
            </View>
              <TextInput
                secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
                multiline={multiline}
                ref={this.setInputRef}
                editable={editable}
                {...props}
                style={[styles.passwordTextInput, editable == false && { color: ColorConstants.TAB_ITEM }, customStyles]}
                keyboardType={keyboardType ? keyboardType : 'default'}
                autoCorrect={false}
                returnKeyType={returnKeyType ? returnKeyType : 'done'}
                placeholder={hint}
                placeholderTextColor={ColorConstants.FEILD_PLACEHOLDER}
                onFocus={() => onFocus ? onFocus : this._changeFocusValue(true)}
                onBlur={() => this._changeFocusValue(false)}
                autoCapitalize={autoCapitalize} />
              {this.props.rightChildren}
            </View>
        );
  }

const styles = {
  viewTextInput: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
  },

  textInput: {
    width: DimensionsValue.VALUE_295,
    height: width / 8.16,
    paddingStart: width / 37.5,
    paddingEnd: width / 37.5,
    fontSize: DimensionsValue.TEXT_M,
    color: ColorConstants.BLACK,
    marginTop: width / 75,
    marginBottom: width / 75,
    borderRadius: DimensionsValue.VALUE_10,
    backgroundColor: ColorConstants.TAB_BACKGROUND,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#DFDFDF',
    fontFamily: AppConstants.FONT_ROBOT_REGULAR,
  },
  passwordTextInput: {
    fontSize: DimensionsValue.TEXT_M,
    color: ColorConstants.BLACK,
    flex: 1
  },
  textLabel: {
    color: ColorConstants.BLACK,
    fontSize: DimensionsValue.VALUE_16,
    alignSelf: 'flex-start',
    fontFamily: AppConstants.FONT_ROBOT_REGULAR,
    marginBottom: 3,
  }
}
```